# Валидация input на лету

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно валидировать `input` на лету, чтобы не давало вводить символ, если строка перестает соответствовать регулярному выражению.

В качестве примера возьму ввод месяца в формате «число и 3 символа месяца».
В таком случае регулярка такая:

```
/^[\d]{1,2}[ ]{0,1}[а-я]{0,3}$/i
```

Если взять событие `keydown` и делать `return false` при несовпадении с регуляркой, то проверяется прошлое значение `input`-а. Если использовать `keyup`, то его уже не перехватить — `return false` не сработает.

Попробовал совместить и промежуточно запоминать строку при `keydown` и возвращать её, если после `keyup` строка не прошла проверку:

```
$strOld = '';
$reg = /^[\d]{1,2}[ ]{0,1}[а-я]{0,3}$/i;

$('.ok').on('keydown', function(e) {
    $strOld = $(this).val();
});
$('.ok').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $val = $(this).val();
    $match = ($reg.test($val));
    if (!$match)
    {
        $(this).val($strOld);
    }
});
```

Но в таком случае можно нажать клавишу и держать. Проверка произойдет только в конце, на последнем символе.

Как решить такую проблему и сделать валидацию по регулярке на лету?

Comment: 1. Используйте `var` (или `let`) для локальных переменных. Не стоит засорять объект `window`. 2. Не стоит в названии всех переменных использовать `$`. Удобно использовать `$` только для обозначения переменных, являющихся jQuery-объектом. 3. Не экономьте не пробелах.

Answer (score 2):

Плагин jQuery Masked Input делает именно то, что вам нужно https://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/

Вы задаете маску и нельзя ввести ничего не соответствующего ей. Для вашего примера с датой можно так:

```js
$.mask.definitions['m']='[а-я]';
$("#date").mask("99 mmm");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="date">
```

Answer (score 2):

Для этого проверку стоит делать прямо в обработчике события `keydown` и проверять не только текущее значение `input`-а, но и вводимый символ. И, в зависимости от результата проверки, либо разрешать добавление символа в `input`, либо нет.
В простейшем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```js
var reg = /^[\d]{1,2}[ ]{0,1}[а-я]{0,3}$/i;

$(".ok").on("keydown", function(e) {
  var newValue = this.value + e.key;
  return reg.test(newValue);
});
```

```html
<input class="ok" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Дабы у пользователя был шанс исправить введённое значение, код можно усложнить (разрешить обработку backspace):

```js
var reg = /^[\d]{1,2}[ ]{0,1}[а-я]{0,3}$/i;

$(".ok").on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.which == 8)
    return true;
  var newValue = this.value + e.key;
  return reg.test(newValue);
});
```

```html
<input class="ok" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Если нужна обработка copy-paste, или возможности перемещаться по значению с помощью стрелок, или ещё что-то в том же духе, то проще и лучше воспользоваться какой-нибудь существующей библиотекой, чем, по сути, создавать свою.

Comment: Невозможно ни стереть значение, ни даже просто передвинуть тестовый курсор стрелками.

Comment: @andreymal да, запрет возможности редактировать введённое значение - это, конечно, жестоко. Как расширенный вариант это добавил.